# get ForeignKey from column name using .__table__.columns._data

Tags: sqlalchemy

I would like to retrieve the foreign key associated with a given column; with the following:

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
Base = declarative_base()

class File(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'file'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    file_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('file.id'))

    myfile  = relationship("File", backref="users",  foreign_keys=file_id)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

print(User.__table__.columns._data)
```

I got what I need, since it prints out

```
{'name': Column('name', String(), table=<users>), 'file_id': Column('file_id', Integer(), ForeignKey('file.id'), table=<users>), 'id': Column('id', Integer(), table=<users>, primary_key=True, nullable=False)}
```

except that I do not known how to retrieve the information, i.e. how to 
parse the output to know that column 'file_id' has foreign key 'file.id'.

Comment: Don't think you should be accessing `_data` directly, as the underscore in the name suggests. `Table.columns` is a collection in itself.

Comment: Maybe; but how does it solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve ForeignKey like this:
`[Class].[column_name].expression.foreign_keys`

In your case:

```
User.file_id.expression.foreign_keys.pop()
```

If you want to get name of foreign key, first you need to add attribute `name` to `file_id`. Example:

```
class User(Base):
    ...
    file_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('file.id', name='user_file_id_fkey'))
```

And then you can use

```
 User.file_id.expression.foreign_keys.pop().name
```